# REST API request authentication

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, mean-stack

I've been trying out the whole MEAN concept of having a REST API for your front-end to access and so on and so forth.

How do I verify that the request to my API is from an ongoing session? Any "token" that I may have the Angular section send in every request for authentication, can be viewed by any person curious enough to look for it.

Said person can take that token and issue "authenticated" requests to the API until the cows come home. How do you get around this?

i.e, I wouldn't like someone with a token use the API to get access to information that may be sensitive to a user etc

Comment: implement HSTS http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/02/01/man-in-the-middle.html

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple mechanism you can use, such as CSRF and CORS to ensure that the request come from a given domain name (ie your own website)